# Question on p. 11 of Bryant, Metric Spaces book

Tags: metric-spaces

On p. 11, the last paragraph says: Confirm by direct integration that $x(t)=1/(1+t)$ is indeed a root of the equation
$$
x(t)=1-\int_0^t [x(u)]^2 \mathrm{d}u.
$$
I am a little confused on how to carry this out.

Update: thought I'd carry it out explicitly for those that come later:

$$
\begin{align*}
x(t)&=1-\int_0^t [x(u)]^2\mathrm{d}u\\
\frac{1}{1+t}&=1-\int_0^t \frac{1}{1+u}^2\mathrm{d}u\\
\frac{1}{1+t}&=\frac{1}{1+t}\quad\text{(integration by substitution steps left out for brevity)}
\end{align*}
$$

Comment: Do you understand what the claim is?

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez, I put part of it as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$x(u) = \frac{1}{1+u}$ and $x(t) = \frac{1}{1+t}$, you just check if these satisfy the equation.

Comment: And of course you find that they do.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but how do I check that they they satisfy the equation?

Comment: By replacing $x(u)$'s expression and integrating, then comparing to $x(t)$.

Comment: You literally just take these two expressions and put them in the equation, then verify that the LHS = RHS. The LHS is ready, but you have to do some calculation in the RHS.

Comment: Ah, the simple things I forget when I don't do calculus for too long...

Answer (score 2):

What is

$$
\int_0^t \frac{1}{(1+u)^2} \mathrm{d}u
$$

??????????????

Comment: Thank you, this helped me. When I carried out the integration I saw that LHS and RHS are equal.